# Jetpack Compose text background with indent

Tags: text, background, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to jetpack compose and i wanat to know if this is possible to achive with jetpack compose. Giving a background to text is very easy with compose but if you want to give indent to background according to text position i don't know where to start an achive this effect.

[Text background with indent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCkbS.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did that:

```kt
@Composable
fun IBgText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    iBgStrokeWidth: Float? = null,
    iBgStrokeColor: Color = Color.DarkGray,
    iBgVerticalPadding: Dp = 0.dp,
    iBgHorizontalPadding: Dp = 0.dp,
    iBgCornerRadius: Dp = 0.dp,
    iBgColor: Color = Color.Gray,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    val vSpace = with(LocalDensity.current) { iBgVerticalPadding.toPx() }
    val hSpace = with(LocalDensity.current) { iBgHorizontalPadding.toPx() }
    val corner = with(LocalDensity.current) { iBgCornerRadius.toPx() }

    var path by remember { mutableStateOf(Path()) }
    fun computePath(layoutResult: TextLayoutResult): Path {

        fun isInnerCorner(
            lr: TextLayoutResult,
            i: Int,
            top: Boolean = false,
            right: Boolean
        ): Boolean {
            if (top && i == 0) return false
            if (!top && i == lr.lineCount - 1) return false
            if (top && right) return lr.getLineRight(i - 1) > lr.getLineRight(i)
            if (!top && right) return lr.getLineRight(i + 1) > lr.getLineRight(i)
            if (top && !right) return lr.getLineLeft(i - 1) < lr.getLineLeft(i)
            return lr.getLineLeft(i + 1) < lr.getLineLeft(i)
        }

        val nbLines = layoutResult.lineCount
        for (i in 0 until nbLines) {
            var top = layoutResult.getLineTop(i)
            var bottom = layoutResult.getLineBottom(i)
            val right = layoutResult.getLineRight(i) + hSpace
            val topInner = isInnerCorner(layoutResult, i, top = true, right = true)
            val bottomInner = isInnerCorner(layoutResult, i, top = false, right = true)
            if (topInner) top += vSpace else top -= vSpace
            if (bottomInner) bottom -= vSpace else bottom += vSpace
            path.apply {
                if (i == 0) {
                    moveTo(right - corner, top)
                } else {
                    if (topInner) {
                        lineTo(right + corner, top)
                    } else {
                        lineTo(right - corner, top)
                    }
                }
                quadraticBezierTo(right, top, right, top + corner)
                lineTo(right, bottom - corner)
                if (bottomInner) {
                    quadraticBezierTo(right, bottom, right + corner, bottom)
                } else {
                    quadraticBezierTo(right, bottom, right - corner, bottom)
                }
            }
        }
        for (i in (nbLines - 1) downTo 0) {
            var top = layoutResult.getLineTop(i)
            var bottom = layoutResult.getLineBottom(i)
            val left = layoutResult.getLineLeft(i) - hSpace
            val topInner = isInnerCorner(layoutResult, i, top = true, right = false)
            val bottomInner = isInnerCorner(layoutResult, i, top = false, right = false)
            if (topInner) top += vSpace else top -= vSpace
            if (bottomInner) bottom -= vSpace else bottom += vSpace
            path.apply {
                if (bottomInner) {
                    lineTo(left - corner, bottom)
                } else {
                    lineTo(left + corner, bottom)
                }
                quadraticBezierTo(left, bottom, left, bottom - corner)
                lineTo(left, top + corner)
                if (topInner) {
                    quadraticBezierTo(left, top, left - corner, top)
                } else {
                    quadraticBezierTo(left, top, left + corner, top)
                }
            }
        }
        path.close()
        return path
    }
    Text(
        text,
        onTextLayout = { layoutResult ->
            path = computePath(layoutResult = layoutResult)
        },
        modifier = modifier.drawBehind {
            drawPath(path, style = Fill, color = iBgColor)
            if (iBgStrokeWidth != null) {
                drawPath(path, style = Stroke(width = iBgStrokeWidth), color = iBgStrokeColor)
            }
        },
        color = color,
        fontSize = fontSize,
        fontStyle = fontStyle,
        fontWeight = fontWeight,
        fontFamily = fontFamily,
        letterSpacing = letterSpacing,
        textDecoration = textDecoration,
        textAlign = textAlign,
        lineHeight = lineHeight,
        overflow = overflow,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        style = style
    )
}
```

Usage:

```kt
@Preview
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Black)){
        IBgText(
            text = "test\ntest test\ntest\ntest test",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 6.dp, start = 10.dp, end = 10.dp, bottom = 6.dp),
            iBgColor = Color.Blue.copy(alpha = .4f),
            iBgStrokeWidth = 3f,
            iBgCornerRadius = 2.dp,
            iBgHorizontalPadding = 5.dp,
            iBgStrokeColor = Color.Red,
            iBgVerticalPadding = 1.dp,
            color = Color.White
        )
        IBgText(
            text = "This is a sample\ntext",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp, bottom = 6.dp).rotate(-15f),
            iBgColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            iBgCornerRadius = 2.dp,
            iBgHorizontalPadding = 8.dp,
            iBgVerticalPadding = 5.dp
        )
        IBgText(
            text = "line 1\n-- line 2 --",
            textAlign = TextAlign.End,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: indented text background]

It is not pretty, but i guess it does the job.

[onTextLayout = { layoutResult ->](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextLayoutResult) gives the boundaries of each line.

[left](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextLayoutResult#getLineLeft(kotlin.Int)), [top](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextLayoutResult#getLineTop(kotlin.Int)), [bottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextLayoutResult#getLineBottom(kotlin.Int)), [right](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextLayoutResult#getLineRight(kotlin.Int))

Then you can make a [path](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Path) going through each line.

I did a loop from the top right corner (1st line end) to the bottom right corner (last line end)

Then another loop from the bottom left (last line start) to the top left (first line start).

Then I added some rounded corners to match the picture.

Ps: I started Kotlin and Jetpack compose this week and spend all my Sunday on your question

Comment: Hi Jfreu. Thanks for the very detailed answer. Seems like modifier.drawBehind() does the trick. Very good implementation. Thanks again